# From a .ppt, produce many .pdf with slight variation

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I have an invitation in `.ppt` format. The first text area starts with `Hello Name,`. I would like to produce 500 `.pdf` documents, where each `.pdf` differ by the `Name` in `hello Name`. The first `.pdf` is for my friend John and it should be written `Hello John,`

I thought I could eventually use some bash script to modify either the `.pdf` or the `.ppt` (if I then manage to build all the `.ppt` automatically). I opened the `.ppt` and `.pdf` with a text editor but I fail to understand how I could modify the files.

How can I best achieve my goal?

Comment: as far as a know This could not be done with only powepoint. but you can do it somewhere else. you could use Indesign (data merge) an ever word itself (mail merge) to do the job. but if you are sticked to PowerPoint. All you have to do is to depend over a third party plugin for PowerPoint something link [datapoint](http://www.presentationpoint.com/software/datapoint/) or [PPTools ](http://www.pptools.com/merge/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use VBA to do this!  You need a list of all the names in an array which you could load from a text file.  Then Loop through them in a suburoutine that you create, for each one taking the name and replacing the text/contents of the appropriate shape on the slide.  You could either immediately print it or save as Slide001, Slide002 for later printing, or even save as PDF, all using VBA commands.